# how to Eloquent join as hasmanythrough

Tags: laravel

I get trouble with my code I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I want to join eloquent as manyThrough but I get wrong relationsship with 'units.material_usage_id'. How to change foreign key id to search id instead ?

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'units.material_usage_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `materials`.*, `units`.`material_usage_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `materials` inner join `units` on `units`.`id` = `materials`.`unit_id` where `units`.`material_usage_id` in (3, 4, 8, 16, 19, 22, 25, 32))
```

My table structure

```
table 1: material_usage
 - worksheet_id (foreign key)
 - material_id  (foreign key of table materials)
 - amount
table 2: materials
 -id(primary)
 -article
 -unit_id (foreign key of table units)
table 3: units
 - id (primary)
 - unit (string)
```

My models:

```
class MaterialUsage extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'worksheet_id', 'material_id', 'amount', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $table = 'material_usage';

    public function material()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Material::class,Unit::class);
    }

    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
    }
}

class Material extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['article', 'unit'];

    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Unit::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
MaterialUsage::where('worksheet_id', $worksheet->id)->with('material')->get();
```

How to get data object that joins all 3 together ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not setup your relations in accordance with the schema you have provided

```
class MaterialUsage extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'worksheet_id', 'material_id', 'amount', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $table = 'material_usage';

    public function material()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Material::class);
    }

    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->belongsToThrough(Unit::class, Material::class);
    }
}

class Material extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['article', 'unit'];

    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
    }
}
```

If the above relations aren't what you were looking for, then you need to change your schema.

** Edit from your comments **

I wasn't reading carefully :( and made a mistake.

You have belongsTo relationships of MaterialUsage to unit and Material to Unit. If that is correct, then you need to install a package that extends the default Eloquent relationships such as [belngsToThrough](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through).

The relationships for your schema have been edited above. Sorry for not catching it the first time :)

Comment: Hello I still get this error. 
<code>SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'materials.material_usage_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `materials` where `materials`.`material_usage_id` in (3, 4, 8, 16, 19, 22, 25, 32))</code> . If need to change schema what I need to do ?

Comment: My current schema is `Schema::create('material_usage', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('worksheet_id')->nullable(false);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('material_id')->nullable(false);
            $table->unsignedDouble('amount', 10, 2)->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('worksheet_id')->references('id')->on('worksheets');
            $table->foreign('material_id')->references('id')->on('materials');
        });`

Comment: `Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('article')->nullable(false);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('unit_id')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('units');
        });`

Comment: `Schema::create('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('unit')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Comment: Hey @Pulsar, I have edited my answer above, hope it helps.